# How do I convert a long[] of thousands of elements to substreams of 100 element chunks?

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm a new to Java Streams, and I've been banging my head against the wall about the "best way" of approaching this particular problem. I have a long[] of as many as 30,000 entries (potentially lots more), and I need to break it up in chunks of 100, and then call an API with the subarray, and keep doing this until all 100-sized chunks have been processed. Also, not all entries in the initial list should be selected. So I need a way of processing the original array, selecting certain elements base on some criteria, and then collecting the "valid" elements in chunks of 100. Obviously I could do this in a loop and simply use a cursor, System.arrayCopy(), or something like that. But it seems inefficient, and I'm very tempted to use the Java Stream API. I've been thinking about a couple of different approaches, but I keep running into dead ends. I'm using filter() with a method reference as argument to do my selection of items from the long[], but I'm stuck on the rest. Any hints are much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify -- Should the order be maintained? For example, should the 1st and 51st elements in the stream (satisfying the predicate) should be in the same chunk, right?

Comment: Hi Kedar. No, the ordering is unimportant. I should have mentioned that in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To divide the array up into chunks, you need to use indices. Streams are not usually a good fit for problems involving indices, but you can get a stream of chunks as follows (here `CHUNK_SIZE` is `100` and `arr` is a `long[]`).

```
IntStream.range(0, 1 + Math.floorDiv(arr.length - 1, CHUNK_SIZE))
         .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, i * CHUNK_SIZE, Math.min(arr.length, (i + 1) * CHUNK_SIZE)));
         ...
```

Note that the last chunk will usually have length less than `CHUNK_SIZE`.

If you want to divide into chunks *after* filtering, you would need to get a stream of the array, do the `filter()`, then use `toArray()` to get a `long[]`, and then divide into chunks as above. It would not be possible to do this as a fluent one-liner.

Comment: Thanks Paul. I was hoping that there would be a way of using Streams to partition the underlying array in filtered chunks of 100, and provide a Stream<long[]> stream that could be used (and possibly parallelized) to consume all the resulting subarrays. Is the array copying in your example necessary? I would have hoped to not have to copy the elements. Also, wouldn't an IntStream or LongStream as in your example above provide a Stream<long> and not a Stream<long[]>?